# the meaning of "lack of necessities" in the sentence

Tags: word-meaning

The sentence says:

> ... a man is not always called unjust because he chooses too much but because he chooses too little of the things that simply and considered in themselves are burdensome -- like labors, **lack of necessities**, and so on.

How do I understand the phrase in this sentence?
Which definition of "necessity" is proper? 
[referring to Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/necessity):

- 1 the state of fact of being required
- 2 an indispensable thing
- 3.1 a condition that cannot be otherwise

And **lack of necessities** should be burdensome according to the sentence, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second definition seems to be correct: "an indispensable thing". That could be food, running water, shelter, etc. As you have noted, the lack of such necessities is burdensome.

Comment: Thanks for your help!